# Implementing JSch to run ssh command in android app

Tags: java, android, ssh, android-asynctask, jsch

I'm currently trying to code up an android app that does a simple "ls" command over ssh to a remote machine. I've tried to use JSch and [this page](http://www.eridem.net/android-tip-021-ssh-execute-remote-commands-with-android), but it just doesn't seem to work. I've looked around and it seems that I have to implement some Async task to run the code. Here is the entire code for the main activity right now:

```
package com.sshtest.sshtest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Properties;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.lang.String;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String string;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


private class sshconnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession("name", "ipaddress", 22);
            session.setPassword("password");

            // Avoid asking for key confirmation
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(prop);

            session.connect();

            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
            channel.setCommand("ls");
            channel.connect();

            InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();


            channel.disconnect();






        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtipinfo);
        txt.setText("Executed");

    }


}
```

- adding uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" to AndroidManifest.xml

This is my first attempt at any serious coding, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call your `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: Ah, it was in the onCreate "sshconnection.execute();" But I get a non-static reference error, I've been trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just want to test. Try not to using AsyncTask, but just simply a thread... like this

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Session session;
            JSch jsch;
            try {
                jsch = new JSch();
                jsch.addIdentity(privateKey, "yourprivatekey");
                session = jsch.getSession("git", "github.com", 22);
                session.setPassword("yourpass");

                // Avoid asking for key confirmation
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(prop);

                session.connect();

                if(session.isConnected()){
                    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " CONNECTED");
                    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " YOO " + jsch.getIdentityRepository().getName()+" "+session.getClientVersion() + " " + session.isConnected());
                }else{
                    System.out.println(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " NOT CONNECTED");
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Call it in the onCreate() method on your Main Activity.
Hope it helped !